# How can i filter the ellbv2(Application ELB) based on their State: Active using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elb

I need to filter ELBV2 based on their state: Active.

Python Code:

```
  import boto3
  elbv2 = boto3.client('elbv2')

  bals = elbv2.describe_load_balancers()
  for elb in bals['LoadBalancers']:
      set2 = elb['LoadBalancerName']
      elbv2_count.append(set2)
       elb2 = len(elbv2_count)
  print('elbV2->'+str(len(elbv2_count)))
```

What i am trying:

```
  available = [i['LoadBalancers'] for i in bals['LoadBalancerName'] if 
              i['State']=='active']
```

getting an error:

```
   KeyError: 'LoadBalancerName'
```

Comment: @John rotenstein, IS there any keyword for ELB to filter based on State: Active

Comment: Please read through [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as the code above is not understandable. Also, the docs are pretty clear that state is available via `bals['State']['Code'] == 'active'`. You might also want to review the waiter for `LoadBalancerAvailable`.

Comment: @dmulter, I am sorry that the code is not understandable. Next time I will make it apt way!!. Thanks for your solution It works. Can you please provide the Docs link where I can see it is mentioned.

Comment: Since you're code was close, I had assumed you've already read through the boto3 docs for [ELBv2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html) and [`describe_load_balancers`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.describe_load_balancers).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it worked with help from Stack overflow users.

What I changed:

```
 bals = elbv2.describe_load_balancers()
 available = [i['LoadBalancerName'] for i in bals['LoadBalancers'] if i['State'] 
 ['Code']=='active']
 print("elbv2 try ->" + str(len(available)))
```

hola!!! It worked. just interchanged the name and elb in for loop and added ['Code']